# Index was out range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: vb.net

Please Help ! i want update data, but i get error message box "Index was out range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index". Database Ms.Access 2010.
And This is my code:

**Update**

```
    Try

        Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)
        Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
        breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
        fsreader.Close()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "UPDATE Tbl_Admin SET Name = @nama, Pwd_Admin = @pass, Information = @info, namafile = @filename, picture = @gambar WHERE ID = " & dg1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & ""
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", TxtNamaAdmin.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TxtPassAdmin.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@info", TxtStatusAdmin.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", LbNamePic.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@gambar", imgbuffer)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
            .Dispose()
        End With

        tampildata()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: I wish everyone would stop doing `Catch ex As Exception`! It is a bad practice (worse than `goto`) and it hides bugs in code.

Answer (score 2):

Below line may be causing the error:

```
.CommandText = "UPDATE Tbl_Admin SET Name = @nama, Pwd_Admin = @pass,
Information = @info, namafile = @filename, picture = @gambar WHERE ID = " & 
dg1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & ""
```

Check for the value of `dg1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value` before running into the command. Most probably there might not be any value with that constraint.

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert your value to integer as below

```
var intdg1selected As Integer =  Convert.ToInt32(dg1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString())
```

Also check your connection name is correct if you have created automatic connection.

Comment: If `dg1.SelectedRows(0),Cells(0).Value` is getting "Index was out of range", assigning the non-accessible value to an integer will not help.